# GoogleApiClient Games.API connect error

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client

I want to use Play Games Services, so I use GoogleApiClient with Games.API and call  method connect(). However it always give error RESOLUTION_REQUIRED in onConnectionFailed().

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener {
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();    }

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    //ConnectionResult{statusCode=RESOLUTION_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{dd739ef: android.os.BinderProxy@624acfc}, message=null}
}
```

But if I use Auth.API instead Games.API, connection was successful and call method onConnected().

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener {
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    //Success
}
```

I using emulator, version of play services in emulator is 10.0, so I set version in gradle build 10.0 too

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.0'
```

I found a same problem here [Google Play fails to connect, statusCode=RESOLUTION_REQUIRED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773062/google-play-fails-to-connect-statuscode-resolution-required), but author didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based from [ConnectionResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult), with error code `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED`:

> Completing the connection requires some form of resolution. A resolution will be available to be started with [`startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#startResolutionForResult(android.app.Activity,int)). If the result returned is `RESULT_OK`, then further attempts to connect should either complete or continue on to the next issue that needs to be resolved.

In addition to that, you may want to also check how you should handle connection failures as discussed in [Manually managed connections](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client). As stated,

> When your app receives a call to the [`onConnectionFailed()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener#onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult))) callback, you should call [`hasResolution()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#hasResolution()) on the provided [`ConnectionResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) object. If it returns true, your app can request that the user take immediate action to resolve the error by calling [`startResolutionForResult()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#startResolutionForResult(android.app.Activity,int)) on the `ConnectionResult` object. The `startResolutionForResult()` method behaves the same as `startActivityForResult()` in this situation, and launches an activity appropriate to the context that helps the user to resolve the error.